# RxJava Chained Observables and NetworkMainThreadException

Tags: android, rx-java

So I have this code:

```
public Observable<AbstractXMPPConnection> connect(final AbstractXMPPConnection connection) {
    return Observable.<AbstractXMPPConnection>create(subscriber -> {
        try {
            AbstractXMPPConnection connection2 = connection.connect();
            if (connection2.isConnected()) {
                subscriber.onNext(connection2);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        } catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    })
    .doOnError(throwable -> LOGI("111", "Connection OnError called"));
}


public Observable<AbstractXMPPConnection> connectWithRetry(final AbstractXMPPConnection connection) {
       return connect(connection)
               .retryWhen(attempts -> attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, MAX_CONNECTION_TRIES), (throwable, integer) -> new Pair<>(throwable, integer))
                       .flatMap(pair -> {
                           if (pair.second == MAX_LOGIN_TRIES)
                               return Observable.error(pair.first);
                           return Observable.timer(pair.second, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                       }));
    }


public void connect() {
        assertTrue("To start a connection to the server, you must first call init() method!",
                this.connectionConfig != null);

        connectionHelper.connectWithRetry(connection)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<AbstractXMPPConnection>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        LOGI(TAG, "ConnectionHelper Connection onError\n");

                        /**{@link LoginActivity#onConnectionFailure(OnConnectionFailureEvent)} */
                        MainApplication.getInstance().getBusInstance().post(new OnConnectionFailureEvent());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(AbstractXMPPConnection connection) {
                        LOGI(TAG, "ConnectionHelper Connection onNext");
//                        onConnected();
                    }
                });
    }
```

I have some questions about chaining observables. Imagining this scenario, in which I have a connect Observable, which sometimes I use, but I use mainly the `connectWithRetry()` Observable.

My question is, what would happen if a added this:

```
.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

To both the `connect()` and `connectWithRetry()`? In this scenario, when I call
public void connect and specify a scheduler, the previous ones are ignored?

And why am I getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`? The explicit `observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` is there, it shouldnt be giving me that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll address your `NetworkOnMainThread` issue first.

`observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` means the *output will be observed* on a new thread - that is, the code in your subscriber (`onComplete/Error/Next`) will be run on that thread.

`subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` means *subscription* will happen on the main thread - the code in your created observable (`connection.connect()` etc) is what is run when subscription happens.

So simply swap the schedulers:

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

So to address your first question, they're not ignored, they're just being used incorrectly. Hopefully from this you can see what would happen if you moved similar calls in to the chain inside your methods that return observables: nothing different to what you've already done. The calls would simply be in a different place.

So where to put the scheduler selection? That's up to you. You may gain increased clarity by *not* having the `subscribeOn` call inside the methods for creating your observables:

```
 connectionHelper.connectWithRetry(connection)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

However, if you feel like you're calling this everywhere for no reason, you can instead move the `subscribeOn` call inside your methods:

```
return connect(connection)
           .retryWhen(...)
           .flatMap(...)
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Note that these don't have to be bundled up together like this - you could `subscribeOn` inside your method, but leave `observeOn` up to any callers that want their results on a specific thread.

Comment: ok so considering i'm specifying two schedulers for each observable, and a third one with the chain, is this wrong? Or should i just simple specify the scheduler only on public void connect? ill accept your answer, thank you for the help

Comment: I've updated the answer with some examples - it's really up to you where you put them! I'm not sure what you mean about a third one, though?

Comment: ok thanks for the extra info i appreciate it :P im my opinion, the names are poorly chosen. I mean, Observable, observer, Subscriber implementing Observer. Its like, subscribeOn is the main problem, because considering when you subscribe to an observable you specify what you want to do with the results, subscribeOn misleads us to "in what thread do you want to do stuff with the results". Imho

Comment: I felt the same way (and faced the same problems), it's a common misunderstanding when starting out with Rx. Once you've spent a bit of time with Rx though, they do make sense. Just takes time to wrap your head around it! Hope everything is clearer now :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try Schedulers.io() may be issue resolve.